# Create a circle at mouse location on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to code a custom mouse trail. To do this I am using temporary divs that appear at the mouse location and fade out after a small interval. Currently the divs only appear at mouse location. I am trying to make them appear at where the mouse is at the moment and stay there while the mouse moves on and draws more divs. Also, how would I add a fade out effect to each individual div so after being placed it would slowly go transparent.

Here's my code so far.

```js
var posX,
  posY,
  paused = null,
  circles = [],
  maxCircles = 30,
  //width & height of div
  circleSize,
  //border radius to make it look like a circle
  rad,
  randCircle;

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < maxCircles; i++) {
    circleSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 5);
    rad = Math.floor(circleSize / 2);
    circles[i] = document.createElement("Div");
    circles[i].style.opacity = "0.6";
    circles[i].className = "circle";
    circles[i].style.width = circleSize + "px";
    circles[i].style.height = circleSize + "px";
    circles[i].style.borderRadius = rad + "px";
    circles[i].style.background = "green";
    circles[i].style.zIndex = "-1";
  }
  $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
    posX = e.clientX - 5;
    posY = e.clientY - 5;
    randCircle = Math.floor((Math.random() * (maxCircles - 1)) + 0);
    if (!paused) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(circles[randCircle]);

      $('.circle').css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: posY,
        left: posX
      });

      paused = setTimeout(function() {
        paused = null
      }, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a very broad question.  How do you determine WHEN to draw the div? And when to NOT draw the div? Would there be multiple divs?

Comment: Why do you create 30 divs then just only use 1 of them?

Comment: Maybe you should show your code to the guys at the code-review SE, they can make your cose style better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your divs change position because you're setting the position of every div with the class name "circle".

You need to change

```
$('.circle').css({position:"absolute", top:posY,left:posX});
```

To

```
circles[randCircle].css({position:"absolute", top:posY,left:posX});
```

To make them fade out you could add an animation to the circles using CSS.

Comment: yeah, that did it! thanks, I'll look into the css fade animation

Comment: @Haq.H no, simply look into CSS animations